# How to solve unresolved dependencies exception in Groovy

Tags: maven, grails, heap-memory

How to solve the unresolved dependencies and java heap space in groovy project..
Even providing MAVEN_OPTS as -Xmx1024m, heap space issue occurring..
Hope someone can help to solve this.

Am using Intellij IDEA, maven 2.2.1, Groovy

```
==== mavenCentral: tried

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/security/jacc/1.0/jacc-1.0.pom

      -- artifact javax.security#jacc;1.0!jacc.jar:

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/security/jacc/1.0/jacc-1.0.jar

        module not found: org.hibernate#hibernate-cglib-repack;2.1_3

    ==== grailsPlugins: tried

      -- artifact org.hibernate#hibernate-cglib-repack;2.1_3!hibernate-cglib-repack.jar:

      C:\Documents and Settings\user\code base\trunk\war/lib/hibernate-cglib-repack-2.1_3.jar

      C:\Documents and Settings\user\code base\war\plugins\.svn/lib/hibernate-cglib-repack-2.1_3.jar

      C:\Documents and Settings\user\code base\trunk\war\plugins\hibernate-1.3.1/lib/hibernate-cglib-repack-2.1_3.jar

      C:\Documents and Settings\user\code base\trunk\war\plugins\jdbc-pool-0.1/lib/hibernate-cglib-repack-2.1_3.jar

      C:\Documents and Settings\user\code base\trunk\war\plugins\tomcat-1.3.2/lib/hibernate-cglib-repack-2.1_3.jar

    ==== grailsCentral: tried

      -- artifact org.hibernate#hibernate-cglib-repack;2.1_3!hibernate-cglib-repack.jar:

      http://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-hibernate-cglib-repack/tags/RELEASE_2_1_3/grails-hibernate-cglib-repack-2.1_3.jar

    ==== grailsCore: tried

      -- artifact org.hibernate#hibernate-cglib-repack;2.1_3!hibernate-cglib-repack.jar:

      http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-hibernate-cglib-repack/tags/RELEASE_2_1_3/grails-hibernate-cglib-repack-2.1_3.jar

    ==== localMavenResolver: tried

      C:\Documents and Settings\user/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-cglib-repack/2.1_3/hibernate-cglib-repack-2.1_3.pom

      -- artifact org.hibernate#hibernate-cglib-repack;2.1_3!hibernate-cglib-repack.jar:

      C:\Documents and Settings\user/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-cglib-repack/2.1_3/hibernate-cglib-repack-2.1_3.jar

    ==== mavenCentral: tried

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-cglib-repack/2.1_3/hibernate-cglib-repack-2.1_3.pom

      -- artifact org.hibernate#hibernate-cglib-repack;2.1_3!hibernate-cglib-repack.jar:

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-cglib-repack/2.1_3/hibernate-cglib-repack-2.1_3.jar

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: javax.security#jaas;1.0.01: not found

        :: javax.security#jacc;1.0: not found

        :: org.hibernate#hibernate-cglib-repack;2.1_3: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


     [copy] Copied 3 empty directories to 2 empty directories under C:\Documents and Settings\user\code base\trunk\war\target\resources
: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:116)
    at _GrailsCompile$_run_closure4_closure10.doCall(_GrailsCompile.groovy:118)
    at _GrailsCompile$_run_closure4_closure10.doCall(_GrailsCompile.groovy)
    at _GrailsSettings$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings.groovy:282)
    at _GrailsSettings$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings.groovy)
    at _GrailsCompile$_run_closure4.doCall(_GrailsCompile.groovy:105)
    at _GrailsCompile$_run_closure3.doCall(_GrailsCompile.groovy:68)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your trace, it looks like the memory issue isn't caused by Maven but while executing some "standard" groovy code. Try raising Groovy's `Xmx` and see what happens.

Comment: I increased Groovy Xmx by adding "JAVA_OPTS -Xmx512M" environmental variable.. Still that heap space issue coming..

Comment: I added -Xmx512M as Vm parameters in runner in run configuration, then the heap issue is solved and dependency issues are also solved..                                                              Now getting                                                 [ERROR] BUILD ERROR

[INFO] Unable to start Grails

Embedded error: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
C:\Documents (Access is denied)                                                              I think the issue is because of space in the file path 'C:/Documents and Settings'  any idea how to solve this issue..

Comment: That's an entirely different question, but it looks like you're having issues with `c:\Documents and Settings` being split into `c:\Documents`, `and` and `Settings`. Your path is incorrectly escaped somewhere.